# Могут ли наречия приобретать функцию вводных под влиянием местоположения?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях? Приобретают ли наречия *"в целом"* и *"однозначно"* функции вводных?

Однозначно (,) «кризис» вносит и коррективы работы с дилерской сетью.

В целом (,) именно в этом письме я не увидел четко сформулированных конкретных проблем, по которым необходимо организовать дискуссию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первой фразе слово "однозначно" употреблено в разговорном  стиле (тем забавнее его соседство с "коррективами" и "дилерской сетью"). Да,  здесь оно в качестве вводного: "несомненно", "безусловно".

Во второй, честно говоря, не понял, что означает это "в целом". По-моему, просто мусор. Но запятую бы поставил.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ну человек как бы обобщает, и запятая как раз и помогает это подчеркнуть, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

> ...вносит и **коррективы работы** с дилерской сетью.

**???**

Наверное, надо так:

*"...вносит и **коррективы в работу** с дилерской сетью"* **?**

Comment: Да, верно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Да, язык развивается, мы стремимся выражать свои мысли короче, поэтому **количество вводных слов увеличивается, пополняется за счет разговорной лексики.**

1) Пример из научного текста, где уже "освоилось" водное слово "в целом":
**В целом**, сигналы домашней кошки по многим параметрам отличаются от сигналов других млекопитающих. [А. П. Дубров,

2) Семантику вводности пока только пытается освоить слово "однозначно": **Однозначно, что** отрицать это нельзя, потому что есть факты.

3) И осваивает: **Однозначно**, олимпиада требует очень обширных, глубоких познаний (Людмила Данилкина.  «Новгородские ведомости»).

Comment: _Sergey: Семантику вводности пока только пытается освоить слово "однозначно": **Однозначно, что** отрицать это нельзя, потому что есть факты._ === Гм... Сергей, а почему Вы решили, что _**однозначно**_ в приведённом Вами предложении  -- вводное?

Comment: Я имею   в виду  семантику слова "однозначно", а не грамматику. Можно сравнить со словом "возможно", которое тоже может быть сказуемым  в безличном предложении (возможно, что) и вводным словом (возможно)

Comment: >> *Однозначно, олимпиада требует очень обширных, глубоких познаний.* Так уже действительно пишут в газетах?! Кашшшмар какой... А *"в натуре"* еще не пишут? Это впереди.